# ggplot2 geom_smooth didn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting two different variables on the same plot. 
sex_female is chr, including 0 and 1. 
epoch_36:epoch_144 are num, time variables.
Here is my code:

```
total %>%
select(sex_female, epoch_36:epoch_144)%>%
gather(key = time, value = ac, epoch_36:epoch_144) %>%
group_by(sex_female,time) %>%
mutate(mean = mean(ac)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = time, y = mean,color = sex_female)) +
geom_point(alpha = .3)+
geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1))
```

After the mutation, I got the tibble:

```
A tibble: 45,780 x 4
# Groups:   sex_female, time [218]
sex_female     time    ac     mean
    <chr>    <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
1          1 epoch_36  49.8 54.96406
2          0 epoch_36  34.7 55.43448
3          0 epoch_36  70.9 55.43448
4          0 epoch_36  12.3 55.43448
5          1 epoch_36 102.7 54.96406
6          1 epoch_36  77.9 54.96406
7          0 epoch_36   1.1 55.43448
8          1 epoch_36 140.0 54.96406
9          1 epoch_36  51.3 54.96406
10          0 epoch_36   0.0 55.43448
# ... with 45,770 more rows
```

I've tried using the solution suggested in a similar question: Plot dashed regression line with geom_smooth in ggplot2, but no lines showed up. How do I fix my code to produce lines?

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the output of `dput()`? Put the name of the data frame in the parenthesis of `dput()`.

Comment: I just figured it out, by unique the tibble, and use the as.numeric. Thanks a lot

Comment: @lila I moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `time` column is categorical and you should transform it into numerical.

```
mutTibble$time <- as.numeric(mutTibble$time)
```

And for plotting you can use this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mutTibble,
       aes(time, mean, color = factor(sex_female))) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.3)+
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
    labs(x = "Time",
         y = "Mean"
         color = "Gender (female)")
```